# JSON file parsing in android offline

Tags: android, json

I have my json file in my raw folder. I have parsed 5 json files. this last one is unable to parse

```
{
  names :
   {
     "appliances" :
         [
            "fan",
            "light"
         ],
     "furniture" :
         [
            "chair",
            "table"
         ]
.
.
.
.
   }
}
```

here i want to use hash map to link it to next table where..
appliances, furnitures are all a seperate json file key and chair, table or all seperate json file key, Here i use Hash Map and vector to map all the keys and values of the three files. Now i just need the Way to use the JSONObject and JSONArray effeciently for this file alone.

For example

```
appliances_groups=parseFile(R.raw.appliances);//function parse file to read json file and store in a string
JSONArray JSONArray_groups= new JSONArray(appliances_groups);
String y ="";
int i;
for (i = 0; i < JSONArray_groups.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject JSONObject_groups = JSONArray_groups.getJSONObject(i);
    HashMap group_elements = new HashMap();
```

then i couldnt proceed
.. here how to effectively use JSONObject ands JSONArray? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use a JSON parsing lib, it's much easier.
Jackson is a really good JSON lib, take a look: [jackson.codehaus.org](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

First steps: [JacksonInFiveMinutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Answer (score 0):

use the code from below link,by using this we can easily parsing the json string

[JSON Parsing](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Comment: Even here is detailed example: **[Android – JSON Parsing example](http://goo.gl/GZE8E)**